# find all substrings between ${ and } in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i have collections of text with some text between ${ and } like "this is ${test} string ${like}". How can I extract all there strings. Output : test,like

Comment: This is not McRegex drive through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
match(/{[\w\d]+}/g);
```

example

```
"{asdas}32323{234}".match(/{[\w\d]+}/g); //outputs ["{asdas}", "{234}"]
```

It will return with `{` and `}` with the matches which you can remove from the resultset by

```
"{asdas}32323{234}".match(/{[\w\d]+}/g).map(function(value){return value.substring(1, value.length-1)}); //outputs ["asdas", "234"]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
"this is ${test} string ${like}".match(/\${\w*}/g).map(function(str){return str.slice(2,-1)})
//["test", "like"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var str = "this is ${test} string ${like}";

var txt = str.match(/{[\w\d]+}/g);

for(var i=0; i < txt.length; i++) {
  txt[i] = txt[i].replace(/[{}]/g, '');
  alert(txt[i]);
}
```